# How to use Data Protection in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to follow [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files) for using Data Protection. However, seeing as it's in Swift, I can't seem to translate it to C# / Xamarin.

To be clear, I don't need the whole code, of course, just where to start. Especially this line:

```
try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .completeFileProtection)
```

I tried several options of translating that into C# but non worked.

Comment: Did your try code in this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16422/ios-file-protection-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

The official Apple Documentation on the Data Protection is available [here](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf).

As Oleg pointed out in the link, and I will summarize it here in case they shutdown the Xamarin Forums:

- First you have to enable Data Protection for your App ID and update your provisioning profiles.
- Set your iOS passcode lock to require passcode "Immediately" and then test it out by launching your app and then locking the device.

```
public static void SetFileProtection(string filePath)
{
    NSMutableDictionary dict = new NSMutableDictionary ();
    var protection = new NSString("NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen");
    dict.Add((new NSString("NSFileProtectionKey") as NSObject), (protection as NSObject));
    NSError error;
    NSFileManager.DefaultManager.SetAttributes(dict, filePath, out error);
    if (error != null)
        System.Console.WriteLine("SetFileProtection Error: " + error.Description);
}
```

You can test the functionality using [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). You will see that the data won't be accessible unless the device is trusted. Choose the appropriate Protection level with the help of the Data Protection Classes in the official docs:

> (NSFileProtectionComplete): The class key is protected with a key
>   derived from the user passcode and the device UID. Shortly after the user
>   locks a device (10 seconds, if the Require Password setting is Immediately),
>   the decrypted class key is discarded, rendering all data in this class
>   inaccessible until the user enters the passcode again or unlocks the device
>   using Touch ID or Face ID.